# Connection to test server by editing hosts file results certificate error

Tags: certificates, hosts, vps

My website running from centos 7 VPS have some compatibility issues, so I purchased a VPS and created a copy of the website and tried to fix them without affecting my website. But the problem is I cannot connect to the vps by entering the ip editing the hosts file. The browsers shows a certificate error saying "You cannot visit xxx.com right now because the website uses HSTS". Tried clearing caches and all, it still have the issue

Please help me to bypass the issue

Comment: Which web #browser# are you using, and on what platform (OS)?

Comment: https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-clear-hsts-settings-on-chrome-firefox-and-ie-browsers

Answer (score 1):

HSTS stands for 'HTTP Strict Transport Security'; basically, it's a header that a website can be configured to send telling browsers that until further notice it should only be accessed via HTTPS -- details in the header specify the exact conditions, but those aren't pertinent to your question.

What happened here is that your current website, which apparently has an SSL certificate (good job!) has HSTS properly configured (Again, good!) but you haven't yet enabled the certificate and HTTPS at the new location for your website (bad!).

Your browser, which has previously visited your old site, remembers the HSTS header and in deference to it refuses to connect to that site without HTTPS (good!) - which your new site doesn't yet support (bad!).

The *proper* solution would be to copy your SSL certificate to the new VPS and set it up properly, at which point your browser should be fine again.

Alternately, [the link](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-clear-hsts-settings-on-chrome-firefox-and-ie-browsers) @gapsf supplied explains how to clear HSTS info from your browser's cache.